# How do I protect the WiFi-network I'm on from worms?

Tags: worm

5 days ago, I downloaded a file from the internet and I'm currently worried about it being malware. I don't store any important information on the computer I downloaded it with, but I'm afraid of the file (if it is indeed malware) spreading to other computers on the network. I don't have shared folders, and every computer on the network has a firewall installed. Are there other things that can be done to prevent a worm from spreading on the network?

Comment: make sure everything is updated: network device firmware, antivirus software, operating systems, etc. and scan the file specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stopping network worms is very simple: configure each device's firewall not to allow incoming connections. That's all you need to do. Bonus points for having a home router that can block the device-to-device traffic.

But that's not the only threat in your story...

> "I don't store any important information on the computer I downloaded
>   it with..."

Yes, you do. You likely store email, account details on all the websites you subscribe to, personal information. Your browsers likely store passwords, and other sensitive information. If you use online banking from that computer, then your bank account is exposed.

That computer also has access to your home router. If your router can be hacked, or if the admin password is weak, then a malicious actor can take over your entire network.

The computer itself can be used as a launching point for attacks outside of your network or a storage point for malicious actors.

So, yes, the worm stuff can be handled simply, but there is a lot more to consider.

Comment: All my accounts aren't that important to me, since I don't use the pc for serious things anyways. How about attacking the router? Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: As with just about everything: make sure it is up-to-date and make the admin password as strong as you can make it (randomly generated and at the maximum length)

Comment: We use a mobile hotspot with unlimited internet, which makes a tablet the router. Does that change anything when it comes to the security? And do you mean the admin password on network or the admin password on the devices?

Comment: I meant the admin password on the router, but frankly, any account with admin access should be at max strength, if you can swing it.

Comment: The mobile hotspot is your router, technically. Your tablet is likely just the UI for it. But then again, it's 2019, and you could have a completely different tech setup than I have experience with.